# SharePoint List dialog box URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, jquery, sharepoint-rest-api

How to get url of List dialog box in SharePoint?
It means that when we click on newform.aspx

How to detect that it is newform.aspx?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding,you want to check whether the URL is new form or not, You can check like this

```
if (window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf("newform.aspx") > 0)
{
  //Do your Operation
}
```

Include this code in your Custom webpart or script editor where to want to check.